# How do I find a suitable copywriter?

Tags: business-writing, marketing

I am in the process of creating a web application.  I will need some copy written for various pages in the site and some of the marketing marketing material.  I am contemplating hiring a copywriter to handle these task for me.  What is the best way to find one?  Also, since I am a programmer, what are some good attributes to look for when trying to find someone?

Answer (score 6):

Another site that offers writing and editing choices is textbroker.com. Editors are rated, as are writers, and they are matched according to compatible levels. I am an editor and have looked into textbroker but, because of my other work, have not yet chosen to participate in their service.

Answer (score 5):

There are many "markets" with copywriters out there.

www.Guru.com is the one I know with the best choices. It has rating systems, so you can know how reliable they are. Usually, they will provide access to previous work, so you will be able to tell if you like how they work. If they are reliable and you like their style... well, that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would say start with people you know.  Always good to get a personal recommendation from someone you trust.  Other than that, I've heard good things about mediabistro.com

Answer (score 0):

there are so many aspects you have to look on before hire a copywriter because on them , your whole project or business is depended.So before hiring a please check:
1.His/her past writing posts.
2Results of previous campaign.
3.compare his/her fee with some other copywriters in the market.
4.Mode of his working.
These are some important keys, on which you must take care of.

[copywriter](http://www.billfryercopywriter.co.uk/)