# What's the best way to break into freelance writing?

Tags: resources, freelance

Are there any good books or Web sites to help get started? I've always had a desire to write and would like to try it out, in this age of the Internet is that the best way to go or are magazines and papers still the way?

Comment: Related: [Finding freelance work](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/finding-freelance-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, even magazines and newspapers are online now. Plus, the responses and results might be a little quicker online. I'd say give them both a try and just see which one gives you more results. I know you can easily search for freelance writing jobs on Craigslist here: http://www.freelancewriting.com/freelancejobs/craigslist.php

There are also countless other sites that were made strictly for helping beginner freelance writers like yourself. Just Google it and see what comes up.

Good luck to you!